# Best approach to clear all service workers on deploy in a reactJS app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I would like to clear or unregister all my service workers when I deploy my reactJS app, ideally some kind of function that will know when a new version has deployed and would run a unregister function to clear the service workers.

Does anyone have any ideas or code examples for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used create-react-app to create my react project. You can get the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app#docsNav)

I just used the code in **src/index.js** like below:

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Then it works when I publish my project online.